# Restore server network after "ip addr flush dev eth0"?

Tags: networking, debian

I had a networking error on an unifi manager server (static IP) and ran the command: "sudo ip addr flush dev eth0" which seemed to help a few people in this [thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/solving-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-when-running-ifup). Which at first sounded logical since I confused it with "flushdns" on windows.

However, I'm now unable to reach the server over the network. I'm not anywhere near the device.

My question is; How do I resolve this error?

Will it start working after I reboot the device (I'll have to ask someone on site to restart it)?
The server also has another network interface, but it's not connected (but then I'll have to ask someone to plug in another ethernet port).
And otherwise I think I'll have to go over to edit /etc/network/interfaces manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it start working after I reboot the device <…>?

Yes, the command you've run merely removed the addresses
assigned to the interface, and this is a purely "runtime-y" thing;
no kind of database of whatever is updated — just some in-kernel runtime
structures.
Rebooting will reconfigure this interface as it was before the
command was run (assumed no changed were made to whatever configuration
venue is used for that interface (`/etc/network/interfaces` or NetworkManager
or `systemd-networkd` or whatever you have configured).

> The server also has another network interface, but it's not connected

What would happen depends on the venue set up for configuring the network,
and whether that interface is configured, and how.
Looks like too many "ifs", to me.

---

If you have anyone with root access to the host, just ask them to execute

```
ip addr add A.B.C.D/NN dev eth0
```

with whatever the `address/netmask` it has before the change.